# DATA/JPA Entity with String key - but replace data when try to save object with same key

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have this Entity class with nickname String as a key.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="players")
public class Player {
  @Id
  private String nickname;
  @Column(name="name")
  private String name;
  @Column(name="surname")
  private String surname;
...
...
...
}
```

Controller

```
  @PostMapping(value="/addPlayer", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces ={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
  public ResponseEntity<Player> save(@RequestBody Player player) throws Exception {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(playerService.save(player), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Service (interface)

```
 Player save(Player player) throws Exception;
```

Service Impl

```
  @Override
  public Player save(Player player)throws Exception{
    if(player.getName() != null && (!player.getName().isEmpty() && (!player.getName().isBlank())) && 
         (player.getSurname() != null && (!player.getSurname().isEmpty() && (!player.getSurname().isBlank()))) &&
         (player.getNickname() != null && (!player.getNickname().isEmpty() && (!player.getNickname().isBlank())))) {
    return playerRepository.save(player);
  }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("provide name,surname and nickname");
  }
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, String> {
//somestuff
}
```

I have this situation in DB.

[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY4jD.png)

If I try this request :

[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBk3C.png)

then in DB i have this bad behavior

[db result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bk8E.png)

Data are overwrite on key " `nickname5` "
work like a patch :( , I don't understand how and why.

I try to add unique annotation at nickname column but not work ...

```
  @Id
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String nickname;
```

Can I ask why i have this behavior and how I can fix it ?

(yes I can do manually with some check in a service but I think I miss some annotation or functionality about data-jpa-framework)

Other than this bug, if you see things that are not right or things that can be done better in the code, I welcome suggestions. I am here to improve .
Thank you !

---

@Edit

I have add the unique constraint on 'nickname' [pk](https://i.postimg.cc/GmHRb359/primary-Key.png)  - [uk](https://i.postimg.cc/jSsnCw7x/unique-Key.png)
But behavior is the same. Name and Username are update if I pass a Nickname(primary-key) already in the database

Comment: If you want a unique value of nickname just add a unique constraint on it, also don’t use it as primary key for it is better to add a Long value and change nickname to a simple column

Comment: @AndreiLisa  already has a primary key constraint ! [link1](https://i.postimg.cc/DyWRR4Xp/db-constraint.png) and after i add unique constraint (on db) -> [link2](https://i.postimg.cc/BQ6134SV/db-constraint-unique.png)
that's why I can't understand
(happy to read you)

Comment: Is there a way (annotation) to put these constraints on the Entity class?

Comment: Can you share full table code from database as a text here ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa sure 
`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.players
(
    nickname character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    surname character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT players_pk PRIMARY KEY (nickname),
    CONSTRAINT players_uk UNIQUE (nickname)
)
`

Comment: give me some time I will write an answer, how to deal with this problem.

Comment: ok , thanks! If you also have suggestions on best practices in particular or clean code (since you've basically seen the whole back end, tell me). In general i don't expone a entity data but create a dto . In this case i need all data in entity then for now i don't create a dto. Controller work with a entity and in a service work with dto . Also have a util package where i convert entity to dto or viceversa that i use in a service...

Comment: i gave an answer, it is what you have to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed into comments this is my answer and some explanation about your case:

First of all you have to avoid using `String` as primary key because in this case because when you are going to add new use with `return playerRepository.save(player);` and a row with the same value as primary key is already persisted to database it will do update instead to throw exception, because `save()` method from `JpaRepository` work so.

> JPA follows the latter approach. save() in Spring Data JPA is
> backed by merge() in plain JPA, therefore it makes your entity managed
> as described above. It means that calling save() on an object with
> predefined id will update the corresponding database record rather
> than insert a new one, and also explains why save() is not called
> create().

In your case you should have something like this one approach:

**Entity:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="players")
public class Player {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "nickname", unique = true)
  private String nickname;

  @Column(name="name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name="surname")
  private String surname;

}
```

**Database Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players
(
    id       bigserial
        primary key,
    name     varchar(255),
    nickname varchar(255)
        unique,
    surname  varchar(255)
);
```

And when you will try to persist a value that already exist in database with the same `nickname`:

You will have the next one exception:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "players_nickname_key" Detail: Key (nickname)=(nickname) already exists.
```

Comment: I had the same solution in mind. 
However, I thought something could be done with annotations or some setting. 
It seems to me to be a limitation to have to necessarily use integers as primary keys and not be able to check strings as keys at save time. 
One can easily work around this (like the solution you proposed). 
I am concerned about the fact that the nickname itself is already a key and unique by definition, so it should already perform the duplicate/conflict checking functions if you try to enter it back into the database. And not update the data with that key (really bad behavior)

Comment: calling save() on an object with predefined id(nickname) will update the corresponding database record rather than insert a new one. In this case you have to follow my solution.

Comment: Yes, understood. You were already clear. It was a simple "complaint." I don't like the default behavior on string keys

Answer (score 1):

You are using a nickname as a primary key in your table. While you've annotated it with ***@Id*** JPA makes it a primary key and it is unique.

As for your ***save()*** method, here it checks whether the object is present or not in **DB** if yes then update else create.

In your ***application.yml***  add

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
```

then you can see the SQL query run by JPA to know how it actually works

Comment: i don't have a *.yml. I use application.properties and spring.jpsa.show-sql=true is just setted. There the settings : [link](https://i.postimg.cc/c41rcXyG/application-properties.png)

Comment: I don't want this behavior. If key is present , i want an error and not a update a data . This behavior is uncorrect. I think spring have a few settings(or annotation) for this. When I do same stuff with a integer key and use a @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) we haven't this behavior(data aren't update). I want an errore that this key already exist in db. 
I want the same on a String nickname